# How I can include .asm file properly?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

When studying assembler at the university, I encountered the following problem:

I have 3 files (all of them oversimplified, they were much bigger):

***main.asm***

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include module.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
TextBuf db 64 dup(?)
Caption db "Test caption", 0
value1 db 25

.code
main:

call StrHex_MY
invoke MessageBoxA, 0, ADDR TextBuf, ADDR Caption, 0

invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main
```

***module.asm***

```
.586
.model flat, c
.code

StrHex_MY proc
xor eax, eax
StrHex_MY endp

end
```

***module.inc***

```
EXTERN StrHex_MY : proc
```

And after trying to compile it I got error:

```
C:\SystemProgramming\lab2copy>ml.exe /c /coff main.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: main.asm

C:\SystemProgramming\lab2copy>link.exe /subsystem:console main.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _StrHex_MY
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How I can include file properly?

Comment: Since you have that setup, you want to assemble `module.asm` as well and then link that to your `main.obj`.

Comment: Which commands in which order I should do? =(

Comment: `ml.exe /c /coff module.asm` and `link.exe /subsystem:console main.obj module.obj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I just was compiling it incorrectly

```
ml /c /coff main.asm
ml /c /coff module.asm
link /subsystem:console main.obj module.obj
```